# How to select all in Open Office writer

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer

I'm going through the process of converting a PDF into a spreadsheet. After some effort, I found that I could get it into an acceptable format for in Writer, then copy it into Calc. But I can't select all, and there are too many pages to select, copy, and past individually. I've tried ctrl A, click and drag selecting, using ctrl and shift click, and 'Select All' in the Edit dropdown menu. I've been able to select at most one page, which isn't really helpful. I also can select all if I add text/stuff that isn't tables, but this stuff messes up the format for pasting into Calc and I can't deselect it before copying

Is there any other way of selecting all I haven't tried?

Comment: **1st**: I fear the question is off-topic here; you should try the sister site https://superuser.com. **2nd**: CTRL+A or "Select All" should do the trick. If they don't, it's difficult to answer without knowing the source document. You should try to create a minimal example that demonstrates exactly where CTRL+A or "Select All" fails.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was on topic either. The topics covered by this site aren't entirely clear to me, but other people have asked openoffice.org questions

Comment: And to clarify, ctrl A or select all do not do the trick (as I said in my original post). I'm not trying to troubleshoot why they didn't work (it's likely a formatting issue), but rather trying to find any alternatives I haven't tried yet